# Did anybody study split homotopy cartesian squares in triangulated categories?

Tags: ct.category-theory, kt.k-theory-and-homology, triangulated-categories

Let us call a commutative square
$$ \require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
  A  @>{g'}>> B \\
 @V{f'}VV     @VV{f}V \\
  C  @>>{g}>  D 
\end{CD}
$$
in a triangulated category   split homotopy cartesian if the ("split") triangle $A\stackrel{f'\bigoplus g'}{\to}C\bigoplus B\stackrel{g\bigoplus -f}{\to} D \stackrel{0}{\to} A[1]$ is distinguished. Certainly, this is equivalent to the existence of an isomorphism $C\bigoplus B\cong A\bigoplus D$ that is "coherent" with these arrows. Yet do you know any criteria that would be "closer to the original square"?

Comment: This sounds like what is called a (homotopy) pushout square in stable infinity-category (or model category). The first chapter of Higher Algebra by Lurie should be relevant. (Topologist like e.g. the example of the singular chains on $U\cap V$, $U$, $V$ and $U\cup V$ for an open cover.)

Comment: If you insist on triangulated categories (as opposed to stable $\infty$-categories, as Lennart rightfully suggests), this kind of things (at least the possibly non-splitted version) is discussed in Neeman's book *Triangulated Categories* (Annals of Math. Studies 148, Princeton Univ. Press) in Chapter 1, §1.4, pp. 52-60. The fact that these define "weak pullbacks" is discussed in Chapter 6, Example 1.6.2, page 184.

Comment: The splitting condition seems to indicate that these actually are pullbacks (and pushouts)...

Comment: Thank you! Yes, they are  pullbacks and pushouts. Possibly, this will help me to find something useful.